# Close messagebox without any action

Tags: c#, .net

I have this sample code to show an alert `MessageBox`,

```
   if (cmprLanguage != 0 || cmprmaxCase != 0 )
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Alert message", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            loginscreen obj = new loginscreen();
            this.Close();
            obj.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            settings obj = settings(); //this re-load this form i need to show this form without reload
            obj.show(); 
            }

        }
        else
        {
            loginscreen obj = new loginscreen();
            this.Close();
            obj.Show();
        }
```

If user clicks cancel button I need to close the `MessageBox`,if they click ok I need to perform the process given inside `OK` block. Now what happen is if I click Cancel button the application redirect to home screen.

Update:

I had written a closed event for close icon in form screen.Previously when i click close icon it directly takes me to login screen because login screen is behind this form screen.Some times user may enter data and without save if he hit close icon i have raise a messagebox to alert the user.But now if i click cancel it again takes me to login screen and if i click ok it perform the task inside the condition.If i click Cancel i need to show the current screen with the action performed(without reload of page)

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: which type of application it is? is it `winform`?

Comment: This looks pretty straightforward. What are you having problems with?

Comment: Exactly. I don't see any problem with the code.

Comment: Maybe he wants it the other way around? User clicks cancel, he wants to show the current data that is not saved, and vice versa. Try switching from `DialogResult.Cancel` to `DialogResult.OK`, see if that matches what you want. I'm just guessing. :-)

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi windows mobile application using compact framework

Comment: @Royal: It's working as expected?

Comment: As Ricky said this seems to already work as expected.

Comment: Its hard to figure out your problem until we see the code inside if else condition.

Comment: What is your expected outcome? Explain what you want to achieve!

Comment: @Ricky i updated the code please see my comments in else part.

Comment: @Royal: Please edit your question and provide substantial information of what you want to achieve. Providing extra information through comments here and there is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already working as expected. But for clearance you could put the result of the `MessageBox.Show()` in a variable instead. This makes it easier to maintain and process in further code. Like this:

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Settings not saved", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
```

And then handle it in code:

```
if(result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //Show new data
}
else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    //Show current data
}
```

**Update:**

Your code is not correct they way you've provided it to us: you cannote have two else statements after eachother.

Why don't you just leave the `else` part away. Only perform an action when the user clicks OK. When the user clicks OK, that means he'll leave the current form without saving the pending changes. When he chooses Cancel, it means that he wants to stay wherever he is at that moment:

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Settings not saved", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //User leaves without saving pending changes
    loginscreen ob = new loginscreen();
    this.Close();
    ob.Show();
}
//No else: just stay wherever you are.
```

Comment: I tried your code but not working as expected.I had written a closed event for close icon in form screen.Previously when i click close icon it directly takes me to login screen because login screen is behind this form screen.Some times user may enter data and without save if he hit close icon i have raise a messagebox to alert the user.But now if i click cancel it again takes me to login screen and if i click ok it perform the task inside the condition.If i click Cancel i need to show the current screen with the action performed(without reload of page)

Comment: You'll have to show the code that is inside the if and else statements. Otherwise we cannot help you further. Place the code in your question and then we can help you further.

Comment: Updated the code please see my comments in else part.

Comment: I tried your updated answer,but sorry again Cancel takes me to Login screen.Initially by default it takes me to login screen to prevent that i put a messagebox to confirm.I think,since by default it takes me to login screen it is happnening(may be default way of working how to prevent default action.

Comment: Then DON'T refer to the login screen by default and do this ONLY when the user clicks OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Settings not saved", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
      loginscreen ob = new loginscreen();
      this.Close();
      ob.Show();
}
```

In my opinion this actually satisfies your needs. It is your original code, let me explain.

The MessageBox gets shown and asks the user if he/she wants to Cancel or agrees (OK) with the data being dropped because the form gets closed. Then, as your code was already designed, it creates a new loginscreen and allows the user to do other stuff.

This actually appears to be all you need. You want the user to stay on the current form is the Cancel-button is clicked, which is exactly what happens if you only use this particular piece of code. No else is needed because nothing else needs to happen.

---

If you do want other code to be executed in the else-statement, you could think about creating a new form and placing OK and Cancel buttons on that yourself (create your own "custom MessageBox"). This will allow you some more options if really needed. But looking at what you are trying to achieve, you are good with the current set up of only an if and no else-statements.